# Visual Studio and CMS?

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2010, html, content-management-system

I have to create an MVC asp.net website using MS visual studio for my final year of study in Information Systems. I want to know if it's possible to sort of "connect" the code to an HTML drag-and-drop CMS, instead of using visual studio's html/css editor and the auto-generated files in the mvc project.

Basically, I want to write the controller and model code in visual studio and the view code (HTML) in a nice CMS such as wordpress or drupal (not necessarily those two).

Please advise!

Comment: You could checkout Umbraco CMS, and write your view code within, though I don't suggest writing view code within a CMS. http://umbraco.com/

Comment: Well i'm more looking to write the view code within visual studio and create the look and feel using the CMS. We have strict deadlines so drag-and-drop would make things go quicker.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider [Orchard CMS](http://www.orchardproject.net/) - it is ASP.net MVC based. It is supported on Azure. Here's an azure+orchard [tutorial](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/tutorials/website-from-gallery/) to get you up and running. [Umbraco](http://umbraco.com/) v6 released in January 2013 also supports MVC.